# How can I make this program running correctly?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to write a java program that reads two integer numbers from the user,
and then displays all the numbers from the first number to the
second number that are divisible by 5 or 6, but not both. The
output should be displayed as ten numbers per line. This is what I got but it's not working .. can someone help?

```
public class Testing {
static int num1;
static int num2;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    userInput();
    factorial();

}

public static void userInput() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
     num1 = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
     num2 = sc.nextInt();
}

public static void factorial() {
    int n;
    int counter = 0;

    for (n = num1; n <= num2; n++) {
        if ((n % 5 == 0 && n % 6 != 0) || (n % 6 == 0 && n % 5 != 0)) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");

            counter = counter++ % 10;
            if (counter == 9) {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

If I enter these integers:

```
Enter first number: 
5
Enter second number: 
90
```

The program displays that I want 10 per line..

```
5 6 10 12 15 18 20 24 25 35 36 40 42 45 48 50 54 55 65 66 70 72 75 78 80 84 85
```

Comment: Describe the problem and show some stacktraces, etc. We don't have anything to go off of

Comment: @AndrewL Ok I included the output

Comment: Try removing that modulus 10. Just increment counter and reset it to 0 when printing a new line..

Comment: @AndrewL But the output is supposed to be divisible by 5 or 6 or maybe I understand the task wrong and just by 5 and 6? 
and its not 10 per line..

Comment: Cool thank you @Manish it works now. :D

Is it supposed to give now all numbers divisible by 5 or 6? 

Write a java program that reads two integer numbers from the user,
and then displays all the numbers from the first number to the
second number that are divisible by 5 or 6, but not both. The
output should be displayed as ten numbers per line.
 
This "but not both" part confuses me

Comment: This means the number should be divisible by either 5 or by 6 but not by 5 and 6 both. Ex. 30 is divisible by both 5 and 6 so it will never be a part of the number you print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is your counter variable.  Since you only want 10 results per line, once counter is greater than or equal to 9 you should break the line with a Println() and then make sure your counter is set back to 0.  See code below:

```
public static void factorial() {
int n;
int counter = 0;

for (n = num1; n <= num2; n++) {
    if ((n % 5 == 0 && n % 6 != 0) || (n % 6 == 0 && n % 5 != 0)) {
        System.out.print(n + " ");

        counter++;
        if (counter >= 9) {
            System.out.println();
            counter = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So he wanted 10 per line, the asker didn't make that clear.

Comment: Thank you Senior @DeadCereal the program is supposed to print numbers divisible by 5 or 6. It still prints both

Comment: @Stiller77 How do you figure, I get the following output from your code: 5 6 10 12 15 18 20 24 25
35 36 40 42 45 48 50 54 55
65 66 70 72 75 78 80 84 85  This seems to be the correct answer.  None of those numbers are divisible by both 5 and 6.  Both 30 and 90 are both missing from the list because they are both divisible by 5 and 6

Comment: @DeadCereal Damn that was a stupid thinking mistake thanks for clearing it out.